# In a group, is any left coset a right coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $\forall a\in G$, is there $\exists\; b \in G$ such that $aH=Hb$?

If $G$ is Abelian or $a\in H$, it is easy to see it is right, but when $G$ is not Abelian and $a \notin H$, I think the answer is no, but I still not find a counter example.

Comment: Look at $S_3$ .

Comment: This condition (every left coset is a right coset and vice versa) holds if and only if $H$ is a **normal** subgroup.

Comment: What examples did you consider to evaluate whether or not they were counterexamples?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $aH=Hb$. In particular, $a\in Hb$, so $a=hb$, for some $b$, so that $b=h^{-1}a\in Ha$. Therefore $Hb=Ha$.

Thus your condition boils down to asking whether $aH=Ha$, for every $a\in G$.